# Python 3.6.4 ODBC Filemaker ProgrammingError: There is an error in the syntax of the query

Tags: python, sql, odbc, filemaker

Hi I'm having some issues reading and updating fields in filemaker using python via ODBC on Windows 10.

I can connect to the database absolutely fine, I get no errors when i run the python file without SQL but for some reason my query's don't want to execute.

```
import pyodbc
Id = '108989'
cstring = "DSN=DB;UID=admin;PWD=password;Trusted_Connection=yes"
con = pyodbc.connect(cstring)
cur = con.cursor()
rows = cur.execute("""UPDATE ACTIVE SET stage='Trans' WHERE __ID=?""",(Id))
del cur, con
print(rows)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/_FM TEST/fmtest.py", line 17, in 
>       rows = cur.execute("""UPDATE ACTIVE SET stage='Trans' WHERE __ID=?""",(Id))
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:51): There is an error in the syntax of the query.\x00\x00ଈ\x9d(\x00\x02Ȁᙙ瞚㾾脀\x00\x00Ɗ謀\x00ˡ\x00\x00(\x00\x02Ȁ\x00\x00㾾脀\x02\x00\x00ˡ\ueda8Þ⪿瞚㍍瞚뒧ꤞȰ\x00\x00ˡ\uedf8Þ\x00ˡ\uee00Þ\x8c\x00샐\uffff\x8e\x00ƣ瞚둧ꤞ\ue760\u0558\x00ˡ\ue768\u0558Ɗ謀타ဓ槔ˡ(\x00\x02Ȁ(\x00㾾脀\x02\x00Ɗ謀 (8310) (SQLPrepare)')

I just moved over to this database from another similar one which worked fine. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you enclose column names that start with special characters in escaped quotes, like this:

> \"__ID\"